# How to install linux on a laptop that doesn't recognise FAT32 bootable media in boot menu?

Tags: usb, system-installation, usb-drive, live-usb

I recently bought an LG laptop, and im looking to install the latest UBUNTU LTS on it. I used rufus to create a bootable usb using FAT32 file format. It doesnt show up in boot menu list. It only appears on boot menu when i create the USB using NTFS file format, but it wont load ubuntu, and leads me to a black screen, "Minimal bash like line editing is supported..." I managed to find a korean article online with a person with the exact same problem as me, and he managed to solve it by reading the grub bootloader off 1 NTFS usb drive and ubuntu files on a FAT32 drive.

I just want to know how you can read the grub bootloader off of another usb drive. Any steps and instructions would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Try [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: YUMI to my knowledge, is not able to have the bootloader on a different file format from the iso file, so both the bootloader and files are on FAT32 file format.

Comment: It has the option to format in NTFS

Comment: Is the partition type set to "EFI System"? Or is it a BIOS system and you didn't install a bootloader in the FAT partition but the formatter added a bootloader to the NTFS filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

**PLAN A:**

Create the LiveUSB on Windows with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), which will prepare a LiveUSB as a bootable NTFS drive, and install the Hybrid ISO of your choice (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, et al.) from the ISO you downloaded in advance.

**PLAN B:**

Put the flash drive in a Windows machine, and use Explorer to check the drive letter assigned to it.

Open a command prompt, and run

```
diskpart
```

then enter

```
list disk  
sel disk N
```

where N is the drive number for the flashdrive. Then do these steps to wipe it clean and make a 4GB partition

```
list part 
select part 1
delete part
create part primary size=4000
```

Leave diskpart with

```
exit
```

Open Explorer and

and format it as FAT16, not FAT32, using X as the drive letter assigned to the flash drive (which we found in the first step).

```
format X:\ /FS:FAT/Q
```

Now you have a FAT16, not FAT32 drive, readable by your LG laptop, ready to turn into a LiveUSB (as Ubuntu wants less than 2GB) with the LiveUSB creator of your choice.

Thanks to  https://www.vmspot.com/format-fat16-usb/ for the suggestion and steps! You can follow along there for illustrations of the process.